# Make a server call when GCM notification Dismiss from notification Tray

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have to make a server call when i dismiss the notification (simply slide it) from my android application, Which event i have to call or what i have to include when in am building the notification ?

Answer (score 0):

I think  [`Notification.deleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) is what you are looking for. The doc says:

> The intent to execute when the notification is explicitly dismissed by the user, either with the "Clear All" button or by swiping it away individually. This probably shouldn't be launching an activity since several of those will be sent at the same time.

**DeleteIntent**:
DeleteIntent is a PendingIntent object that can be associated with a notification and gets fired when the notification gets deleted, ether by :

- User specific action
- User Delete all the notifications.

You can set the Pending Intent to a broadcast Receiver and then perform any action you want.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
  Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
 ..... code for your notification
  builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             .... code to handle cancel
         }

  }
```